# Receber um único dado de um nó do Firebase

Tags: android, firebase

Eu gostaria de saber como recuperar do Firebase um unico dado do FireBase, eu usei a estrutura do EventListener montando o objeto e puxando apenas um dos dados, porem ao executar o app da erro e fecha, talvez seja erro no caminho especificado, mas não sei como prosseguir. Como fazer isso recuperar apenas 1 dos dados de um nó ???

### Fragment

```
public class fragmentPerfil extends Fragment {
private DatabaseReference databaseReference;
private FirebaseAuth autenticacao;
private TextView nome;
private String usuarioLogado;

public fragmentPerfil() {
    // Required empty public constructor
}


@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_noticias, container, false);

    nome = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.txt_nome);

    autenticacao = FirebaseConfig.getAutenticacao();
    autenticacao.getCurrentUser();
    usuarioLogado = autenticacao.getCurrentUser().getUid();
    databaseReference = FirebaseConfig.getFirebase().child("Usuarios").child(usuarioLogado);
    databaseReference.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            Usuarios user = dataSnapshot.getValue(Usuarios.class);
            nome.setText(user.getNome());

        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });



    return view;
  }

}
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Olá,

```
FirebaseConfig.getFirebase().child("Usuarios").child(usuarioLogado);
```

Vai retornar o objeto inteiro de "Usuarios", se quiser retornar somente o "nome", faça assim:

```
FirebaseConfig.getFirebase().child("Usuarios").child(usuarioLogado).child("nome");
```

Ai o seu retorno no

```
 public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
```

Será uma string. Para pegar ela ficaria assim:

```
String nome = (String) dataSnapshot.getValue();
```